# Java Regex Cannot Match One Line Comment

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I am writing a compiler for a Java-like language and need to match occurrences of one-line comments of the style `// Comment.` for my tokenizer.

My attempt:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MatchOneLineComment {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("//(.*)").matcher("//abc");
    System.out.println(matcher.group()); // should print "//abc"... right?
  }
}
```

However I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:485)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:445)
    at MatchOneLineComment.main(MatchOneLineComment.java:7)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to call [`Matcher#find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29)

```
matcher.find();
```

and check the result before you call `group()`.

From the javadoc

> Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that
>   matches the pattern.
>
> This method starts at the beginning of this matcher's region, or, if a
>   previous invocation of the method was successful and the matcher has
>   not since been reset, at the first character not matched by the
>   previous match.
>
> **If the match succeeds then more information can be obtained via the
>   start, end, and group methods.**

Comment: Thanks, this was my problem. Will accept in a minute.